# Is there any uv-vis sensor that installs on a pipe like other measurement tools like flowmeter or temperature sensor?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I am looking for an industrial UV-vis sensor that is installed on a pipe like other measurement instruments like temperature and flow transmitters.

I researched this subject and I found one model but not too many.

It looks like it's not common, and it's quite expensive.

I would like to hear from you if you have any experience.

---

Can I find a cheaper alternative sensor to analyze what's inside a pipe?